# cast a stream or byte array to object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stream, arrays, deserialization

In our game, to save a "Ghost" (a serializable class which is record of how someone played a level), we use straightforward

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
object ghost = bf.Deserialize(file);
file.Close();
return (Ghost)ghost;
```

Which works perfectly, and to save a Ghost,

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream file = File.Create(filePath);
bf.Serialize(file, ghost);
file.Close();
```

Again, perfect.

Thing is, we're loading things from the web too (specifically Amazon S3), which, in the end, gives a generic stream.

What I want to do is save that stream to file,

```
using( BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream) )
{
    FileStream file = File.Create(downloadPath);
    byte[] array = ReadAllBytes(reader);
    file.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    file.Close();
}
```

*But also* deliver those bytes back to the requesting code, to be able to cast them into the Ghost object.  Currently, we save the ghost, tell the requesting code it's been saved, and they just read it from there again, which works, but I'd be 99% sure that that's an unnecessary step when we already have the bytes available to us.

Slightly c# noob, and every example I've seen about deserializing has involved `File` objects.  Any pointers would obviously be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've already got the serialized byte array then just create a MemoryStream from that and use the BinaryFormatter to deserialize from there.

Comment: I don't actually need to.  The `stream` that's already there is compatible already, and the BinaryFormatter can take that, as @CCondron answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of a Memory Stream work just the same as the File Stream. The examples you have should work the same way with the memory stream replacing the file stream. 
You can also do this in unsafe code, but that seems overkill for what you trying to do here.
Something like this should work:

```
 var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
 object ghost = bf.Deserialize(stream);
 return ghost;
```

There should be no need for the reader, but I don't know what kind of stream your getting.

and of course once you have the ghost object in memory, serialize a copy to disk.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.  I had been on the `BinaryFormatter` API page and everything, but completely missed the stream option for deserialisation.  It's the move from Eclipse I think that's affecting me more, I would have checked every one of it's code hints, poking around in the class definition had I been using that.  Ah well, some day I'll be comfortable in MonoDevelop!  Thanks @CCondron.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the `BinaryFormatter` is to be avoided according to official .NET documentation: [BinaryFormatter security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide).

Some recommended alternatives are:

- `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` for serializing/deserializing objects into and from XML;
- `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` for XML and JSON data formats;
- `System.Text.Json` APIs for serializing/deserializing objects into and from memory to JSON.